# fopen Called From AJAX Request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-io

I'm building a WebApp that needs to send a text and a filename through AJAX to the PHP script(on the same place as the Javascript source of course) and the PHP script should save this file on the server, but how to make this?

Comment: When asking for code, please give something you've started with.

Comment: @contagious I'm not asking for code, instead I'm asking for help. You could answer me with some sites that could present me some examples and explanation and I would love and if the site is really good I would accept as best answer for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds very simple actually. You just send your AJAX request:

```
$.post("file.php", {filename:"text1.txt", text:"..."});
```

And in PHP only need:

```
file_put_contents($dir.basename($_POST["filename"]), $_POST["text"]);
```

Obviously you need a bit more authorization, a pre-defined save `$dir` and using `basename()` is only the minimum security precaution.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and you'll do it like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.post('yourscript.php', {filename: 'output.txt', content: 'hello world'});
</script>
```

Instead of constants you can use textfields for your values. e.g.

```
$.post('yourscript.php', {filename: $('#filename').val(), content: $('#content').val()});
```

*filename* and *content* within the $-function are the ids of your textfields.